# Do I need to fill the gap of a wide tv mount hole?

Tags: hole, television, mount

First time mounting a TV here. The Mounting Screw Holes at the back of my TV is wider than the M6 screw that it takes. I was wondering if I need to fill the gap with a spacer or something else when mounting the brackets. Any help will be appreciated.

This is how it looks:
[image]

Comment: the threaded component is most likely connected to a metal sub frame .... also the manufacturer designed the mounting system to hold up the TV without a filler (unless fillers were included with the TV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the mount bracket is secured solidly to the TV, and not putting lots of pressure on one particular spot of the plastic chassis, no, you don't need spacers.

I've had mounts that come with spacers but it really just depends on the design of the TV and mount. If you can notice the plastic flexing while you put the mount on, then you should probably consider spacers or a different style mount.

Comment: Right. If you're concerned because it's a very heavy TV, apply some double-sided foam tape between the mount plate and TV. This will eliminate the shear load on the screws.